# JSON Path of property/value of specific location in json String

Tags: c#, json

That lacked clarity - my apologies. So let me clarify:
Consider the following JSON string:

```
{"cmd":"setParam","ref":"name","bs":{"Ubat":"5330","Usolar":"199","Uext":"104","SOC":"935","btFlags":"160","btCur":"-1092","temp":"-950","detVolt":"6825","detCur":"6"} }
```

I select a random index into that string, for illustration purpose, 83
I'm looking for a method that returns the path to the property name at the location 83: `$.bs.SOC`

I came across [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZ1zLg) that gets the value(s) of a given property, for example "honda":

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = jo.Descendants()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Where(p => p.Value.ToString() == "honda")
                    .First();
```

I'm not looking for the value, but for the path. Thank you!!

Comment: Voting to close as needs details / clarity.

Comment: What is your reason for needing this?

Comment: The problem is unclear and you haven't shown what you have tried

Comment: Clarified the qustion - hopefully sombeody can help, thanks